# Why my asynctask class only show three items?

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I have a problem with the AsyncTask class. My problem is that my class only shows the three values ​​"name" json array and it should show 5 or more. Does anyone know the error?

**My json array:**

```
{"productos":[{"id_oferta":"197","total":"3","nombre":"nombrE","precio":"4.30-20.50","imagen":"http:\/\/www.ofertapp.es\/images\/app\/comercios\/4.jpg","descripcion":"Breve descripci\u00f3n del negocio. El cual, se ofrece varios servicios como por ejemplo: \u00bfA qu\u00e9 p\u00fablico va dirigido? \u00bfCuantas unidades contiene?\u00bf D\u00f3nde est\u00e1 localizado? Por otro lado, decir que la oferta s\u00f3lo estar\u00e1 disponible en los meses Noviembre y Diciembre. Para poder disfrutar de esta oferta simplemente dir\u00edjase a nuestra tienda y te daremos instrucciones. Esperamos verte por aqu\u00ed y que disfrutes s\u00f3lo, con tu pareja o amigos.","direccion":"direccion","telefono":"telefono","latitud":"37.119571803396475","longitud":"-5.451107025146484","horariomanana":"9:40","horariotarde":"20:00","email":"email@email.com","id_cat":"1","id_usuario":"10","disp":"1","actions":[]},{"id_oferta":"199","total":null,"nombre":"migato","precio":"3","imagen":"http:\/\/www.ofertapp.es\/images\/app\/comercios\/gatp.jpg","descripcion":"424","direccion":"424","telefono":"42","latitud":"37.119330660753164","longitud":"-5.449090003967285","horariomanana":"7:50 - 20:","horariotarde":"21:00","email":"asd@ads.com","id_cat":"1","id_usuario":"7","disp":"1","actions":[]},{"id_oferta":"200","total":"2","nombre":"nombre2","precio":"4.30","imagen":"http:\/\/www.ofertapp.es\/images\/app\/comercios\/5.jpg","descripcion":"desc","direccion":"direccion","telefono":"telefono","latitud":"37.119571803396475","longitud":"-5.451107025146484","horariomanana":"","horariotarde":"","email":"","id_cat":"1","id_usuario":"7","disp":"1","actions":[]},{"id_oferta":"201","total":"2","nombre":"Nombre43","precio":"4.30","imagen":"http:\/\/www.ofertapp.es\/images\/app\/comercios\/6.jpg","descripcion":"desc","direccion":"direccion","telefono":"telefono","latitud":"37.119571803396475","longitud":"-5.451107025146484","horariomanana":"","horariotarde":"","email":"","id_cat":"1","id_usuario":"7","disp":"1","actions":[]},{"id_oferta":"203","total":null,"nombre":"Probando","precio":"3.30-20.50","imagen":"http:\/\/www.ofertapp.es\/images\/app\/comercios\/35.jpg","descripcion":"desc","direccion":"direccion","telefono":"telefono","latitud":"37.119571803396475","longitud":"-5.451107025146484","horariomanana":"9:40","horariotarde":"20:00","email":"email@email.com","id_cat":"1","id_usuario":"7","disp":"1","actions":[]}],"errorCode":0,"errorString":"Todo correcto"}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static String url = "http://www.url.domain";
    JSONArray user = null;
    private static final String TAG_USER = "productos";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "nombre";
    private static final String imagen = "imagen";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

        new JSONParse().execute();
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Obteniendo datos ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONfromURL(url);
                    Log.e("count -> ", ""+json.length());
                   //SHOW 5 items
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();      

            try {
                // Getting JSON Array
                user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String image = c.getString(imagen);
                    Log.e("count...",""+id);
                                    //SHOW 3 ITEMS, WHY?
                }    
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**JSONParser.class**

public class JSONParser {

```
public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    // Download JSON data from URL
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient() ;

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
        // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used. 
        int timeoutConnection = 10000; //3Segs == 3000
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 15000; // 5000 == 5 segs
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

        /* CODE RESPONSE */
        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        //Log.e("responseCode","" + responseCode);
        String ss = response.getStatusLine().toString();
        //Log.e("responseCode","" + ss);

        if (responseCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } else {
            Log.e("responseCode","");
        }

    }catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }  catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    // Convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

}
Can anyone help me? Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one error for sure, which explains why you get 3 here when you do:

```
user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) { // should be user.length() !
    ...
}
```

You should iterate the `user`, which is a JSONArray of the users, and indeed contains 5 entries. When you do `json.length()` you are actually counting how many key/value entries the response has, which is 3 (productos, errorCode, errorString).

However(!) this doesn't explain why you get 5 here:

```
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONfromURL(url);
Log.e("count -> ", ""+json.length());
```

Since it seems to be the same response JSONObject, and not the `user` array...
Hopefully this can set you on the right track to solve though.